# Changing Scenes In Spritekit, Detecting Touches on Buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am attempting to change from a home scene to a game scene in Spritekit. When I run it in the simulator, there is no transition to the GameScene. I also added a print command to see if the touches on the play button were even being registered, and they were not. Here's the code. Thanks!

```
import SpriteKit

class HomeScene: SKScene {

    var playButton: SKSpriteNode?
    var gameScene: SKScene!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    playButton = self.childNode(withName: "startButton") as? SKSpriteNode

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let pos = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = self.atPoint(pos)

        if node == playButton {
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
            print("touch")
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: you do not want playButton to be optional, use `lazy var playButton = {return self.childNode(withName: "startButton") as! SKSpriteNode}() `. Then, the first time you call playButton, it will do the search and remember it.  If it crashes, then you know you have a problem with the scene finding play button, do not switch back to `as?` in an attempt to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `touches` parameter inside of your `touchesBegan(_: with:)` method is of type `Set<UITouch>`, i.e. a set of touches. As stated in the [Apple Documentation for Sets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set), a set is used when the order of the items in the collection are not a concern. Therefore, you cannot assume that the first item in `touches` is the first touch in the set. Knowing this, I recommend refactoring your code inside of HomeScene.swift to the following:

```
import SpriteKit

class HomeScene: SKScene {

    private var playButton: SKSpriteNode?

    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        self.playButton = self.childNode(withName: "//starButton") as? SKSpriteNode
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches {
            self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self))
        }
    }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        let nodes = self.nodes(at: pos)

        if let button = playButton {
            if nodes.contains(button) {
                let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                self.view?.presentScene(gameScene)
        }
    }
}
```

The `touchDown(atPoint:)` method does all the heavy lifting and `touchesBegan(_: with:)` is freed up to listen for touch events. Another thing to note when calling `childNode(withName:)`:

- Adding `/` before the name of the file starts searching for nodes beginning at the root of your file hierarchy.
- Adding `//` before the name of the file starts searching for nodes beginning at the root of your file hierarchy, then recursively down the hierarchy.
- Adding `*` before the name of the file acts as a character wildcard and allows you to search for file names that are wholly or partially unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the node's name instead of the node itself for comparison in the touchesBegan... try something like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class HomeScene: SKScene {

    var playButton: SKSpriteNode?
    var gameScene: SKScene!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        playButton = self.childNode(withName: "startButton") as? SKSpriteNode

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let pos = touch.location(in: self)
            let node = self.atPoint(pos)

            if node.name == "startButton" {
                let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
                gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
                self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
                print("touch")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)